# Filter data before displaying in the component in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I have a list of football data coming from an api.

[image]

All the available list are shown when I request this api endpoint. I am trying to separate the list based on the status of the game. For eg. Finished, Postponed, Timed.

I tried something like this

```
<div *ngFor="let fixture of fixtures">
    <div *ngIf="fixture.status !== 'FINISHED'">
        <p>{{fixture.date}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It gets filtered and doesn't show on the view but it isn't filtered completely. Now the problem is that, since the list is too long, I want to show only first 20 items and I am doing as below:

```
<div *ngFor="let fixture of fixtures | slice:0:20">
    <div *ngIf="fixture.status !== 'FINISHED'">
        <p>{{fixture.date}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As it should show up only the first 20 items from the list of filtered items but it didn't. It doesn't show any list because the list is still there that isn't filtered.

Now I think the way I am filtering at the moment isn't the right way. Since it gets filtered only in the view but not in list coming from the api, when I try to slice the list, it doesn't work like this.

Please let me know if you people can help me achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not** use the `slice` pipe like that, it won't work well in conjunction with your `*ngIf`; it knows nothing about the filtered result set, only the original list.

Before I give the solution, take a look at the source code of the `slice` pipe to see how it works internally on your list:

```
@Pipe({name: 'slice', pure: false})
export class SlicePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, start: number, end?: number): any {
    if (value == null) return value;

    if (!this.supports(value)) {
      throw invalidPipeArgumentError(SlicePipe, value);
    }

    return value.slice(start, end);
  }

  private supports(obj: any): boolean { return typeof obj === 'string' || Array.isArray(obj); }
}
```

As you see, it takes in an original list (which would be the filtered result set in this case), and THEN it slices it.

Source: [Angular.io](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.9/packages/common/src/pipes/slice_pipe.ts#L11-L70)

---

To solve your problem, filter in your component, and loop through the filtered results in your template. Then and only then should you apply the `slice` pipe.

This is more efficient (because you aren't looping needlessly in the component), and allows you to run more operations on the filtered lists since you have them cached.

**Component:**

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
    list: any[] = [...];
    fixtures: any[] = this.list.filter(item => item.status !== 'FINISHED');
}
```

**Template:**

```
<div *ngFor="let fixture of fixtures | slice:0:20">
    <p>{{fixture.date}}</p>
</div>
```

---

**Update:**

To fix your problem with searching, search against the original list, not the filtered list.

Comment: I understand what you mean and I think this is the right way to do it. But how is it possible to get the `status` in the component, since I can get this only in the view after `ngFor` loop.

Comment: Why can't you get the status in the component? If the list you're rendering to the template comes from your component, then you must be able to access it there. Can you explain, please?

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Now I am having another problem with the search. Before slicing I was able to search from the whole list of items. But now it isn't working as before since it only search from the sliced items. Any idea about this :)

Comment: Updated. Actually didn't require me to write any code. I think that answer should be sufficient. Just change the list you're searching from the filtered list to the original list containing everything. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can I search from the original list. `<div *ngFor="let fixture of filteredFixtures | slice:0:20 | searchClub: leagueClubs">`. I have search in the filtered list, how can I make it on the original list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167351/discussion-between-lansana-and-surazzarus).